# Does the '__min_lv_minval' make sense?

Tags: c++

In <Inside The C++ Object Model>, chapter 4, Explanation for the inline function:

```
min(int i, int j) {
    int minval = i < j ? i : j;
    return minval;
}
//Expanded in line
{
    int minval;
    int __min_lv_minval;

    minval = (__min_lv_minval = val1 < val2 ?  val1 : val2),
       __min_lv_minval;  // There is a '__min_lv_minval' here. Why?
    // vs minval = (__min_lv_minval = val1 < val2 ?  val1 : val2); 
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to actually contain a question (the title should be a short summary, not the main question).

Comment: The book describes inline expansions in much more detail than a post on SO should, and there is plenty of explanation for this in the surrounding text. There's also a note saying that it's not necessary, in theory, in that example.